# sapply() Returning Surprising Result - R

Tags: r, function, vector, sapply

I am using glm() to create a few different models based on the values in a vector I make (h1_lines).  I want sapply to return a model for each value in the vector.  Instead, my code is currently returning a list of lists where one part of the list is the model.  It seems to be returning everything I do inside the sapply function.

```
train = data.frame(scores=train[,y_col], total=train[,4], history=train[,5], line=train[,6])
h1_lines<- c(65, 70, 75)

models <- sapply(h1_lines, function(x){
                 temp_set<-train
                 temp_set$scores<-ifelse(temp_set$scores>x,1,
                                     ifelse(temp_set$scores<x,0,rbinom(dim(temp_set)[1],1,.5)))

                 mod<-glm(scores ~ total + history + line, data=temp_set, family=binomial)
                                    })
```

I'd like the code to work so after these lines I can do:

```
predict(models[1,], test_case)
predict(models[2,], test_case)
predict(models[3,], test_case)
```

But right now I can't do it cause sapply is returning more than just the model... If I do print(dim(models)) it says models has 30 rows and 3 columns??

EDIT TO ADD QUESTION;

Using the suggestion below code works great, I can do predict(models[[1]], test_case) and it works perfectly.  How can I return/save the models so I can access them with the key I used to create them? For example, using the h1_scores it could be something like the following:

```
predict(models[[65]], test_case))

predict(models[[key==65]], test_case)
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data? `train` references itself.

Comment: Also, your function in `sapply` (which should be `lapply`, per @Señor O's answer) should probably `return` something.

Comment: Technically `mod` will get returned since it's the last line the braces, but I agree it's better to explicitly mention what's getting returned for readability.

Comment: good point Thomas, i just added the line "return(mod)" using the sapply command and it works identical to lapply now.  actually i was trying that before but got confused with r data structures and was trying to access the results with models[1,] when in fact it is models[[1]]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `lapply` instead of `sapply`.

`sapply` simplifies too much. Try:

```
lapply(ListOfData, function(X) lm(y~x, X))
sapply(ListOfData, function(X) lm(y~x, X))
```

I don't know exactly the distinction, but if you're ever expect the output of each item of `sapply` to have extractable parts (i.e. `Item$SubItem`), you should use `lapply` instead.

**Update**

Answering your next question, you can do either:

```
names(models) <- h1_lines
names(h1_lines) <- h1_lines ## Before lapply
```

And call them by

```
models[["65"]]
```

Remember to use quotes around the numbers. As a side note, naming list items with numbers is not always the best idea. A workaround could be:

```
models[[which(h1_lines==65)]]
```

Comment: `sapply` tries to use `simplify2array` when all of the values are of the same length.

Comment: its ironic that sapply tries to "simplify" but returns a more complicated and "thorough" result than lapply

Comment: senor o, that works great, i updated above with a follow up question